# R plot, x-axis and y-axis touching

Tags: r, plot, axis, smoothing, curve

My problem concerns the making of a graph for a publication in R. I have used the plot function like follows:

```
plot(x=data$SL, y=data$BD, xlab = "SL (mm)", ylab = "BD (mm)", pch=data$pch)
```

SL ranges from 51.7 to 73.7 and BD from 13.5 to 20.4. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post images yet.

However, wanting to get rid of the box I used "axes=F". Problem now is lack of control over the axis function. I used:

```
axis(side=1, lwd=3, xpd=TRUE, at=c(min(data$SL):max(data$SL)))
axis(side=2, lwd=3, xpd=TRUE, at=c(min(data$BD):max(data$BD)))
```

Problem is that I can't manage to get the y- and x-axis to come together on the same point as in the plot with the box. How to let the x- and y- axis to touch each other?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely setting xaxs = "i" and yaxs = "i" will help you getting the desired behaviour.

```
plot(c(1,2,3),c(2,4,6),axes=F,xaxs = "i",yaxs="i",xlim=c(0,3),ylim=c(0,6))
axis(side=1, lwd=3, xpd=TRUE, at=0:3)
axis(side=2, lwd=3, xpd=TRUE, at=seq(0,6,2))
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `box(bty='L')` to draw only the left and bottom parts of the box.  You could also just draw the lines yourself using `lines`, `segments`, or `abline` and using `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` functions to find the locations where to draw the lines.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you follow the procedure you outlined and then use:

`box(which = "plot", bty = "l")`

e.g.:

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(1, 18), ylim = c(2, 20))
points(1:18, 2:19, pch = 1, col = "#FF7F24", cex = 1.2)
lines(1:18,  2:19, col = "#FF7F24", lwd = 2)
axis(side      = 1,
     lwd       = 0,
     lwd.ticks = 1,
     at        = 1:18,
     cex.axis = 0.9)
title(main = "Plot",
      ylab = "Y-Axis")
legend("top",
       legend = c("Legend"),
       col = c("#FF7F24"),
       text.col = c("#FF7F24"),
       pch    = 1,
       bty    = "n",
       cex    = 1.2)
axis(side      = 2,
     lwd       = 0,
     lwd.ticks = 1)
box(which = "plot", bty = "l")
```

You should pass the options `lwd = 0` and `lwd.ticks = 1` to your seperate `axis()` calls in order to prevent some parts of your axes to appear fatter than other parts of your axis because some get overlayed by your call to `box()` and some do not.

The solution of using `box()` at the end is, I think, more general in that you can use it when e.g. you cannot or do not want to pass `bty = "l"` in your `plot.default` or `plot.window` call.